# How to round off a ratio to the lowest integral value in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data in column 'day', which is calculated by finding difference between two dates and this tells me the number of days it took for a person to complete an activity. I want to represent the column 'day' in weeks in the following manner.

6 days = 6/7 = 0 week

I tried rounding off but it is getting rounded to the highest integral value rather than the lowest integral value. Below is the query used by me.

```
SELECT ROUND(DATE_PART('day', '2011-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp - '2011-12-26 00:00:00'::timestamp)/7)
```

[The expected and actual results are as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf0rA.png)

Comment: What is the data type of day?

Comment: @forpas i am calculating day using date_part function between two dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `floor` function instead of `round`.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`date_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-datetime.html) returns a double precision number and not an integer, so the result of the division is not an integer.
So use the function [`trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/functions-math.html) to remove any decimal digits from the result of the division:

```
SELECT day,
trunc(day/7)
FROM Activity
```